# Install error on installing Developer 2k 1.2.1on Virtualized Windows NT

Tags: windows, oracle, windows-nt

I am trying to install Developer 2k 1.3.2 on a virtualized windows nt system. I am facing the following access exception.

*An application error has occurred log has been generated 
ORAINST.exe
Exception: Access violation (0xc0000005) , address:0x00ea78ea*

Can anyone help me understand what might be going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you opening a database museum? This version is released in 1996....